# Fcm Notification not triggered in background or when device is rebooted

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing FCM in my application , so basically i have some data that i send using data-payload , onMessageReceived() is successfully triggered when app is on foreground , but when i rebooted my device for example , notification is not triggered , i tried all possible ways to solve this issue but no luck ,
Help is appreciated guys , thank you .

- This is my data - payload

```
 val notificationData = JSONObject()
        val payload = JSONObject()

        notificationData.put("to", "/topics/$userToken")
        payload.put("title",title)
        payload.put("body", body)
        payload.put("notificationVibrate",isVibrationEnabled)
        payload.put("notification_channel_id",getString(R.string.channelid))
        notificationData.put("data", payload)
```

- This is how i'm receiving data in my firebaseMessagingService

```
 override fun onMessageReceived(remotemessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remotemessage)
        if(remotemessage.data.isNotEmpty()){
            val data = remotemessage.data
            val title = data["title"]
            val body    = data["body"]
            val isVibrationEnabled   = data["notificationVibrate"]?.toBoolean()
            val notificationChannelId = data["notification_channel_id"]

            FireNotification(title!!,body!!,isVibrationEnabled!!,notificationChannelId!!)
        }
    }
```

- This is the function where i fire the notification

````
private fun FireNotification(title : String , body : String,isVibrationEnabled : Boolean,notificationchannelid : String){

        val vibratePattern = longArrayOf(500L,500L,500L)
         val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, notificationchannelid)
        notification.setContentTitle(body)
        notification.setContentText(title)
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_active_24)
        notification.setAutoCancel(true)
        if(isVibrationEnabled){
            notification.setVibrate(vibratePattern)
        }
        notificatomCompat.notify(1001, notification.build())
    } ```
````

Comment: This is fine. Please share the code for `FireNotification(...)` method

Comment: I have updated the code and you can check it out now

Comment: This should be working fine. Have you tried to log and see if your methods are being called?

Comment: well basically when the app is on foregroud the notifications is there after receiving data in onMessagedReceived() but for example when i reboot the device , nothing shows up , and yeah my method is called as i said on foreground but not on background weird .